# Regular Expression: How to match using previous matches?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am searching for string patterns of the form:

```
XXXAXXX 
# exactly 3 Xs, followed by a non-X, followed by 3Xs
```

All of the Xs must be the same character and the A must not be an X.

*Note: I am **not** searching explicitly for Xs and As - I just need to find this pattern of characters in general.*

Is it possible to build this using a regular expression? I will be implementing the search in Python if that matters.

Thanks in advance!
-CS

**Update:**

@rohit-jain's answer in Python

```
x = re.search(r"(\w)\1{2}(?:(?!\1)\w)\1{3}", data_str)
```

@jerry's answer in Python

```
x = re.search(r"(.)\1{2}(?!\1).\1{3}", data_str)
```

Comment: In addition to consulting the answers below, you may wish to look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: You can use `x = re.search(r"(.)\1{2}(?!\1).\1{3}", data_str)` to avoid double escaping.

Comment: Sweet - thanks Jerry!

Comment: @CaymanEss Also, I'm a bit confused as to why you put `\n` in the negative lookahead, because it actually breaks the regex, see [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/xC3iK9). If you remove the `\n`, it works fine, see [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/gR9kW5).

Comment: @Jerry Typo... sorry. :(

Comment: It's okay, don't worry about it. Also, you can use the site I have linked to test your regular expressions :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(\w)\1{2}(?!\1)\w\1{3}
```

**Break Up:**

```
(\w)        # Match a word character and capture in group 1
\1{2}       # Match group 1 twice, to make the same character thrice - `XXX`
(?!\1)      # Make sure the character in group 1 is not ahead. (X is not ahead)
\w          # Then match a word character. This is `A` 
\1{3}       # Match the group 1 thrice - XXX
```

Comment: You might want to rephrase "word" as "word character", just to be clear.

Answer (score 4):

You can perhaps use this regex:

```
(.)\1{2}(?!\1).\1{3}
```

The first dot matches any character, then we call it back twice, make use of a negative lookahead to make sure there's not the captured character ahead and use another dot to accept any character once again, then 3 callbacks.